# Don't know if it is obvious, but how do I fit the following model in R?

Tags: programming, regression

From the Paper "momentum crashes", Daniel and Moskowitz

[image: From the Paper "momentum crashes", Daniel and Moskowitz]

$I_B$ is a dummy Variable which could be either one or zero

Is it possible to regress on two intercepts? or do i get something wrong ?
Are there options to create my own linear regression model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do: run the regression twice.

The first time use only the time periods with $I_{t-1} = 0$

The resulting Alpha and Beta will be estimates of $\alpha_0,\beta_0$

Now run the regression a second time, using the other data points, those with $I_{t-1} = 1$. The resulting Alpha and Beta are estimates of $\alpha_0+\alpha_B,\beta_0+\beta_B$. By subtracting the already known $\alpha_0,\beta_0$, you can find $\alpha_B,\beta_B$.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
just one thought left: since it is called conditional CAPM, doesn't the compare group (you suggested as first regression: I = 0) hast to be the whole sample, so the unconditional fit (so alpha(0) contains all values, alpha(b) only I=1)

Comment: nvm since checking with the solutions your attempt makes sense
thanks!